# Mapped typed to make all properties required

Tags: typescript

A TypeScript class can have optional properties and required properties.

```
class SomeClass {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: string;
  baz: string = '';
  qux: string = '';
}
```

The `Partial<T>` mapped type can make all the properties optional.

```
type SomeClassPartial = Partial<SomeClass>;
```

The question is, can we go the opposite way and make all the properties required?

```
type SomeClassComplete = Complete<SomeClass>;
```

The `Partial` mapped type adds a `?` to all the properties, thereby making them all optional. What I am looking for is a way to remove the `?` from all the properties, thereby making them all required.

We tried using the `!` operator but it is doesn't have that semantic.

```
type Complete<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Found it. The `Required<T>` partial does this.

The definition is [inside TypeScript/lib.es5.d.ts here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a3c22683ab7462dc71935b3219098a3a3c98c9ea/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1418-L1423).

```
/**
 * Make all properties in T required
 */
type Required<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
};
```