# Require optional field in certain case

Tags: typescript

please advise.
I have an interface:

```
export interface PermissionScope {
  type: string;
  companyId?: number | null;
}
```

Later, in certain case i want to require `companyId` field be present. What is the most effective typescriptish way to do it?

Appreciate.

Comment: Elobrate your question and requirement.

Comment: To require all fields, `Required<PermissionScope>`. To just change that one field,  `Omit<PermissionScope, 'companyId'> & Required<Pick<PermissionScope, 'companyId'>>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883393/5385381

Comment: Dear @Aluan Haddad, thanks for the solution. If you put it as an answer, i'll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Aluan Haddad:

To require all fields, `Required<PermissionScope>`. To just change that one field, `Omit<PermissionScope, 'companyId'> & Required<Pick<PermissionScope, 'companyId'>>`